# Getting NameError: name 'teams' is not defined with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping, nameerror

I try to webscrape a gemble site, when i delete the print code I don't get an output just (process finished with exit code 0) I don't know what the problem could be

This is the code ->
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

```
options = Options()
options.headless = False
web = 'https://fezbet1.com/en/sport?sportids=1'
path = r'C:\Users\Senne\Desktop\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe'

options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path, options=options)
driver.get(web)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

frame_ref = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")[1]
iframe = driver.switch_to.frame(frame_ref)

box = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('asb-flex-col.asb-cut.asb-pos-wide._asb_events-table-row ')

for data in box :
    teams = data.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="sb"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]').text
    odds = data.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="sb"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div').text

print(teams,odds)
```

### THE ERROR SAYS=

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Senne\PycharmProjects\webscrapin\main.py", line 25, in <module>
print(teams,odds)
NameError: name 'teams' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
------------------
```

Comment: If `box` is empty, that loop will never be entered, and `teams` and `odds` will never be set. Also, you likely don't want to reassign those variables each iteration since then you lose the previous results and will only keep the last. You likely want to create lists before that loop, then `append` to the `teams` and `odds` lists.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to locate the object box(using class_name), but the object is not present on the DOM. Try adding implicit wait using `sleep(5)` before `box = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('asb-flex-col.asb-cut.asb-pos-wide._asb_events-table-row ')`.
You are getting this error because the box is empty.

Comment: Do you mean with     sleep(5) driver.implicitly_wait(5) ?

Comment: I placed it before the box = ... but I still don't get an output

Comment: Now try 2 things:
1. add explicit wait `sleep(5)` using time module
2. `print(box)` right after assigning. If its empty then your specified class_name is wrong

Comment: The output i get is [] that means its empty right ?

Comment: I'm gonna try and search for the correct class

Comment: yes this means your class name is wrong. try id or any other capturing element